# How does the `quote` macro achieve interpolation?

Tags: rust, scope, macros, hygiene

How do the `quote` (declarative) and `proc_quote` (procedural) macros allow interpolation of local variables?

Since (declarative) macros are hygienic, I would expect that they wouldn't be able to access the environment they're called in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since (declarative) macros are hygienic, I would expect that they wouldn't be able to access the environment they're called in.

Why though?

```
vec![a, b, c]
```

works fine.

Macros being hygienic doesn't mean they can't access the environment they're called in (that would make them completely useless), it means they don't *accidentally affect* the environment they're called in, that is, the internal symbols of the macro will neither leak into nor conflict with environment symbols.

For instance using C macros, the names inside and outside of the macro live in the exact same namespace, so it's possible to have collisions and odd side-effects.

Comment: I think where the OP might be confused is that a macro like `format!` _needs_ the first parameter to be a constant literal. This question would be better if it explained why those are different.

Comment: I haven't realized that the macro expands to the old environment which is "how it accesses it" :) It just doesn't access it at all; interpolation is just marking that something is to be treated as a variable, not to be quoted but e.g. being moved to a method.

Comment: @mcarton From what I've got from the library source, `format!` and friends is ultimately internal to the compiler, which therefore requires the string to be known at compile time.